# MS Exchange Server requests for “Activate Device Administrator” permissions on mobile devices

Tags: exchange

trying to add MS Exchange account to built in mail.
If I activate Email app as device admin, can it really erase all data on device? 
Thanks

```
- Erase all data: Perform a factory reset, deleting all of your data without any confirmation
- Limit Password: Restrict the types of passwords you are allowed to use. 
- Watch login attempts: Monitor failed attempts to login to the device, to perform some action 
- Force Lock: Control when device locks, requiring you re-enter its password.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the point.

If an employee looses the device you can have the device wipe all data, this protects company information.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following similar threads which about the feature **Activate Device Administrator** on the Android devices:
**[“Activate Device Administrator” permissions on mobile devices](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33b502d1-6dbb-40b1-b2a1-9145a2577ef0/how-to-turn-off-ms-exchange-server-requests-for-8220activate-device-administrator8221?forum=Exch2016GD)** & **[Exchange - Android - Activate Device Administrator](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2145661-exchange-android-activate-device-administrator)**. Hope they are helpful to you.